# BigQuery Concatenate a List into a String with quotes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Example Table1:

```
ID   Color
143  Blue 
213  Black
934  Green
902  Red
894  Orange
```

The result I'm looking for is a string like this = ('143','213','934','902','894')

I started off with "SELECT ID FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID"

I know I could write a long manual statement like this: " ' " + SELECT ID FROM Table1 LIMIT 1 + " ',' " + SELECT ID FROM Table1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 + " ',' " +....

However my actual table is 100k+ rows long with 2000+ unique IDs so this isn't possible.

Comment: Why do you want a string?  Arrays are usually more convenient to work with in BigQuery.

Answer (score 4):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT("'", CAST(id AS STRING), "'"))
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

this assumes the `id` field is not a string - but if it already string - you can omit use of CAST

Answer (score 3):

One method is:

```
SELECT CONCAT("('",
              STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CAST(id AS STRING), "','"),
              "')"
             )
FROM t;
```